# Moment of inertia regarding square lamina

Tags: moment-of-inertia

[image]

The above is a square lamina of length $a$ and mass $m$. We are interested in finding the moment of inertia of it when it is rotating with a diagonal as the axis.

Now my approach is using perpendicular axis theorem. The blue lines are the axes parallel to the sides and the moment of inertia with respect to any one of them is well known to be $I_{\mathrm{axis}}=\frac{ma^2}{12}$. So by perpendicular axis theorem, the moment of inertia with respect to the green line(*the axis perpendicular to the plane of the lamina*) is $I=2\times I_{\mathrm{axis}}=\frac{ma^2}{6}$. Now,we consider the moment of inertia with respect to the diagonals. As we can see,the *green line* is perpendicular the the diagonals as well since it is perpendicular to the plane. So,again by perpendicular axis theorem, $I=2\times  I_{\mathrm{diagonal}}$. Since we already determined the value of $I$, so our answer should be $\frac{ma^2}{12}$.

But it seems like that's not the case. We now imagine the lamina being divided into two halves each containing a triangle. So the moment of inertia of any one triangle is well known to be $\frac{mh^2}{6}=\frac{ma^2}{12}$ where $h=\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}$ is the height. Hence the moment of inertia of the whole lamina is $2\times \frac{ma^2}{12}=\frac{ma^2}{6}$.

The second solution is given in the books and the first one is mine. Surely i made a mistake somewhere but everything seems fine to me. Did i then use perpendicular axis theorem wrongly? Please enlighten me.

Comment: I suppose you got the moment of inertia about the diagonal to be $ma^2/12$

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you got the moment of inertia about the diagonal to be $mL^2/12$. I think the second solution might have a mistake, as if you divide into two triangles each has a mass m/2 of total, so the m in your final expression isnt the mass of lamina.